# synchronizing on DropBox data between all app users

Tags: xcode, dropbox

I am creating an app which saves same files on dropBox, in the app folder. all the saved files uploaded by all app users should then be displayed in a table view. the result which I got is that only the user's files are shown, but I would like the data do be synchronized among all app users. I posted a question of this kind on dropbox developer forum and this was the answer:

"The Dropbox API is built to sync files within each specific authorized account, not between all authorized accounts.

If you do need to copy files between accounts, check out the new /copy_ref call:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#copy_ref"

...

"This really depends on the structure/use of your app. If it's just an iOS app, with no server side component, you'll need to build some way for users to send the copy references to each other."

I so tried to understand what the copy ref was, but It isn't very clear. do they mean that I need to build a server like mySql to do this, or can I integrate the ability to share all the data in the app itself??